# Is there a Python equivalent for Swift's @dynamicMemberLookup?

Tags: python, swift, monkeypatching, keypaths

In `Swift`, you can define `@dynamicMemberLookup` ([see documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID585)) to get direct access to properties that are nested inside another type. Is there a `Python` equivalent?

### Example of what I want to achieve with `Python`

Let's say I have a class with members, e.g.:

```
c = OuterClass()
c.inner_class = ClassWithManyMembers()
c.inner_class.member1 = "1"
c.inner_class.member2 = "2"
c.inner_class.member3 = "3"
```

I would like to be able to get/set those members without having to type the `inner_class` every time:

```
print(c.member1)  # prints "1"
c.member1 = 3
print(c.member1)  # prints "3"
```

### Example in `Swift` ([Source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID585)):

#### Dynamic member lookup by member name

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct DynamicStruct {
    let dictionary = ["someDynamicMember": 325,
                      "someOtherMember": 787]
    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> Int {
        return dictionary[member] ?? 1054
    }
}
let s = DynamicStruct()

// Use dynamic member lookup.
let dynamic = s.someDynamicMember
print(dynamic)
// Prints "325"
```

#### Dynamic member lookup by key path

```
struct Point { var x, y: Int }

@dynamicMemberLookup
struct PassthroughWrapper<Value> {
    var value: Value
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember member: KeyPath<Value, T>) -> T {
        get { return value[keyPath: member] }
    }
}

let point = Point(x: 381, y: 431)
let wrapper = PassthroughWrapper(value: point)
print(wrapper.x)
```

My only idea in `Python` would be to `monkey-patch` all nested properties directly to the outer class.

Comment: The use case you called Dynamic by member name works straight away in python. Just you don't a function to access a dict item. dyn = s.someDynamicMember, then dynamic['whatever']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can just save a reference to the inner object when you want to make repeated accesses to it.

```
c = OuterClass()
c.inner_class = ClassWithManyMembers()

ic = c.inner_class
print(ic.member1)
print(ic.member2)
print(ic.member3)

ic.member1 = "5"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against nesting classes in one another, but if you must do it, try this:

```py
class MetaOuter(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        for member in cls.__dict__.values():
            if hasattr(member, attr):
                return getattr(member, attr)
        raise AttributeError(attr)

    def __setattr__(cls, attr, value):
        for member in cls.__dict__.values():
            if hasattr(member, attr):
                setattr(member, attr, value)
                return
        super().__setattr__(attr, value)


class Outer(metaclass=MetaOuter):
    a = 0

    class Inner:
        x = 1
        y = 2
```

Now any attributes of a nested class inside `Outer` are available (and can be written to) as an attribute of `Outer`:

```py
>>> Outer.x, Outer.y
(1, 2)
>>> Outer.a # Accessing regular attributes still works as usual
0
>>> Outer.x = True
>>> Outer.Inner.x
True
```

If you need to nest more than one level, use the same meta class for any inner encapsulating classes:

```py
class Outer(metaclass=MetaOuter):
    a = 0

    class Inner(metaclass=MetaOuter):
        x = 1
        y = 2

        class Innerer:
            z = 42
```

```py
>>> Outer.a, Outer.x, Outer.y, Outer.z
(0, 1, 2, 42)
>>> Outer.z = -1
>>> Outer.z
-1
```

Note: Be aware that if you're trying to access an attribute that is found in multiple nested classes, you can't be sure of which class the attribute will come from. A more predictable implementation in this case would be to handle some kind of key path that will be looked up, but that's essentially the same as what Python provides by default (e.g., `Outer.Inner.Innerer.z`).

Comment: Does this also work with directly accessing values from a dictionary in my class (instead of the nested class example)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you give a code example of what you would like to be able do (in Python)?

Comment: This isn't really about nested classes, just about accessing the attributes of an attribute directly.

Comment: @chepner The solution you posted is the one I have been using. I just wasn't sure if there might be a generic approach to make any nested property available without having to save the reference to the inner property everytime. However, my question/example was `class` focused, so this was bad on my part. You guys are both right and both helped me. Thanks!